# C++: std does not have member "string"

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2012, c++11, namespaces

I have coded the following:

```
STDMETHODIMP CWrapper::openPort(LONG* m_OpenPortResult)
{
    std::string str;
    //const char * c = str.c_str();
    // Open("test".c_str())

    return S_OK;
}
```

The compiler tells me "There is no such member "string" in the namespace std".

My includes look like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Wrapper.h"
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
```

Did I do anything wrong so far?

Comment: Did you #include <string>?

Comment: `string` and `string.h` are two different header files.

Comment: @olevegard Ah, yes, super. Now that I use include <string>, it works.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to add the following:

```
#include <string>
```